# Capturing graphql data key between the first opening curly bracket and the second opening parenthesis

Tags: regex, typescript, graphql

I am trying to write a regex in an effort to refactor some end-to-end tests on a GraphQL API.

Here are some example of what I'd like to capture:

```
query SignIn($payload: AuthCredentialsInput!) {
  signIn(payload: $payload) {
    token
  }
}
```

Should retrieve `signIn`

```
mutation SendConfirmationEmail($athleteId: ID!) {
  sendConfirmationEmail(athleteId: $athleteId) {
    id
  }
}
```

Should retrieve `sendConfirmationEmail`

```
mutation CreateProgram($title: String!) {
  createProgram(title: $title) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

Should retrieve `createProgram`

```
query GetAllExerciseTemplates {
  getAllExerciseTemplates {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

Should retrieve `getAllExerciseTemplates`

At the moment I need to pass those key by hand for every end-to-end test.

My best attempt is this regex: `.+?\{+[ \r\n\t\f\v ](.+)\(`

```
    const regexTest = query.query.match(/.+?\{+[ \r\n\t\f\v ](.+)\(/)
    console.warn(regexTest)
```

But the result is this:

```
  console.warn
    [
      'mutation CreateProgram($title: String!) {\n          createProgram(',
      '          createProgram',
      index: 0,
      input: 'mutation CreateProgram($title: String!) {\n' +
        '          createProgram(title: $title) {\n' +
        '            id\n' +
        '            title\n' +
        '          }\n' +
        '        }',
      groups: undefined
    ]
```

Any regex expert that can solve it here?

EDIT : Here is the best shot I did, yet it could be great if I could have only one regex instead of two

```
function getDataKey(query: Query) {
  const keyBeforeFirstParenthesis = /.+?{[\r\n\t\f\v ]+(.+)\(/
  const keyBeforeFirstBracket = /.+?{[\r\n\t\f\v ]+(.+) {/

  let regExpMatchArray
  regExpMatchArray = query.query.match(keyBeforeFirstParenthesis)
  if (!regExpMatchArray)
    regExpMatchArray = query.query.match(keyBeforeFirstBracket)

  return regExpMatchArray[1]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two regexps into

```js
/.+?{\s*(.+?)\s*[({]/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ejzasR/1/). *Details*:

- `.+?` - one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `{` - a `{` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[({]` - `(` or `{` char.